# Struggling to template a WPF MenuItem's Icon with control

Tags: c#, wpf

Following on from a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45943272/wpf-context-menu-data-bound-icon-only-appears-when-inspected), I'm struggling to style a `MenuItem`'s `Icon` with a control I have that inserts icon images based upon a string dependency property.

Initially I started with:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
    <ContextMenu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            ...
            <Setter Property="Icon">
                <local:StringToIcon IconName="{Binding IconName}" />
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.Resources>
</ContextMenu>
```

This had the predictable effect of only displaying one of the icons in the menu, usually the last one, as the instance was shared around.

I then tried the non-shared resource approach:

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
    <ContextMenu.Resources>
        <local:StringToIcon x:Key="MenuIcon" x:Shared="False" IconName="{Binding IconName}" />
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            ...
            <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuIcon} />
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.Resources>
</ContextMenu>
```

This had no effect. It didn't offer me `x:Shared` in Intellisense, so I wonder if that's an invalid property here.

Out of desperation, I threw the thing into a template:

```
<Setter Property="Icon">
    <Setter.Value>
        <ContentControl>
            <ContentControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <local:StringToIcon IconName="{Binding IconName}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ContentControl.Template>
        </ContentControl>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Again, no effect. My `StringToIcon` looks like this at the moment, hard-coded with a single image to check the problem doesn't lie there. (Or does it?)

```
<UserControl x:Class="RAP.Admin3.Components.StringToIcon"
    ...
>
    <Image DataContext="{Binding ElementName=StringIconControl}" Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Icons/lorry.png"/>
</UserControl>
```

How do I get this darn thing to template and allow multiple uses? It's probably something basic I'm overlooking.

I've looked at various similar questions, and most seem to have success with the non-shared resource method.

**Edit**: Let me add substantially more code as requested. I've come up with a minimal replication of the problem:

The context menu is part of a TreeView resource.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.ItemHierarchy"
             ...
             Name="ItemHierarchyControl">
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ItemHierarchyControl, Path=Items}">
            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HierarchyItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Subitems}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,1,4,1">
                        <TextBlock Text="My text" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                            <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
                                <ContextMenu.Resources>
                                    <local:StringToIcon x:Key="MenuIcon" x:Shared="False" IconName="{Binding IconName}" />
                                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                        <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuIcon}" />
                                    </Style>
                                </ContextMenu.Resources>
                            </ContextMenu>
                        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

This is backed by a dependency property for the items.

```
public ObservableCollection<HierarchyItem> Items
{
    get { return (ObservableCollection<HierarchyItem>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<HierarchyItem>), typeof(ItemHierarchy), new PropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<HierarchyItem>()));
```

`StringToIcon` is also backed by a string dependency property for the icon name, which is summarily ignored because of the hard-coded image at the moment.

`HierarchyItem`s are simple for the example:

```
public ObservableCollection<HierarchyItem> Subitems { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<BindableMenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
```

Just to get this proof working, I attached the `ItemHierarchy` to some properties of the main window:

```
public ObservableCollection<BindableMenuItem> MenuItems { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<HierarchyItem> IHItems { get; set; }
public MainWindow()
{
    MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<BindableMenuItem>();
    MenuItems.Add(new BindableMenuItem("Item", null));
    MenuItems.Add(new BindableMenuItem("Item", null));
    MenuItems.Add(new BindableMenuItem("Item", null));
    MenuItems.Add(new BindableMenuItem("Item", null));

    IHItems = new ObservableCollection<HierarchyItem>();
    IHItems.Add(new HierarchyItem() { MenuItems = this.MenuItems });

    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Edit 2: Here's `BindableMenuItem` also:

```
public class BindableMenuItem
{
    public BindableMenuItem(string name, ICommand command)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Command = command;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
    public string IconName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<BindableMenuItem> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your non-shared resource approach should work. Please provide a full repo of your issue when asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @mm8 Do you have something specific you'd like to see the code for? The non-shared resource approach doesn't seem to work. The last icon in the context menu appears, but none of the others do. Reducing the number of entries means the displayed icon shifts upwards.

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" is not much of help I am afraid. It works for me but of course I can't run your code since you haven't posted it.

Comment: @mm8 I've added the full context of the context menu within its user control, and trimmed things down to a minimum viable example. Does that help? Let me know if any of the smaller elements are needed.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using a converter?  It seems to me you are trying to do something very simple and have gotten stuck down a blind alley.  Why not simply use a converter to convert view model string to an icon.  I'd post a solution but I am worried that I haven't untangled your question enough to figure out if this is what you are trying to do.

Comment: @AQuirky I'd considered that, or even letting each VM load its own icon from resources. But both options seemed very un-MVVM; instead, the VM says what icon it needs by name, and the front end then decides what that looks like. Fishing out icons in converter code _feels_ wrong, though I'm not wholly sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move the `StringToIcon` to `<TreeView.Resources>`:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=ItemHierarchyControl, Path=Items}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <local:StringToIcon x:Key="MenuIcon" x:Shared="False" IconName="{Binding IconName}" />
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:HierarchyItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Subitems}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,1,4,1">
                <TextBlock Text="My text" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
                        <ContextMenu.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                                <Setter Property="Icon" Value="{StaticResource MenuIcon}" />
                            </Style>
                        </ContextMenu.Resources>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Oh good grief, that was it? Thank you! I'd ruled out moving it there because I figured the IconName binding wouldn't work, as the context would be the TreeView. Does the binding get evaluated in the context the resource is used or something?